# Mongoid, after_create hook cannot modify self

Tags: mongoid

The below after create hook does not successfully set the gdoc key. We have to use `self.write_attribute` instead. Am I trying to do something stupid?

```
class GoogleDoc
  field :gdoc_key, type: String
  field :filename, type: String

  after_create :after_create_hook
  def after_create_hook
    self.gdoc_key =  "qwerty"
    self.save
  end
end
```

Thanks!
Jonathan

Answer (score 4):

From [Durran](https://github.com/durran)

You cannot call save in an `after_` hook since you're going to cause the document to fire the callbacks in an infinite loop. You'll need to use something that doesn't fire callbacks, like update_attribute.

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2974

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `gdoc_key` in `before_create`

```
before_create :set_gdoc_key
def set_gdoc_key
  self.gdoc_key = 'qwerty'
end
```